# Ruby/Rails content_tag isn't rendering correctly (ruby 1.9.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here below the start of my menu_builder method in the applicationhelper (in the view: <%= menu_builder(@page); %>):

```
def menu_builder(page)
  items = [ "home", "faq", "store" ]
  content = ""
  items.each do |i|
    content << content_tag(:a, "#{i.capitalize}", :href => "/#{i}" )
  end
  return content
end
```

I would like to render links not tags. I should miss somthing here but I don't find..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it like this:

```
def menu_builder(page)
  items = [ "home", "faq", "store" ]
  content = ""
  items.each do |i|
    content << content_tag(:a, "#{i.capitalize}", :href => "/#{i}" )
  end
  content.html_safe
end
```

Or modify your template like this:

```
<%= raw menu_builder %>
```

Use any.